# Is $\{1, 2, 3\}\times \Bbb Z$ uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\Bbb Z$ being the set of integers. 
 
My understanding is that a set is uncountable if it's greater than the set of $\Bbb N$. 
Might it be that I'm misunderstanding the question, and misinterpreting the '$\times$' which I'm currently interpreting as 'intersection'.

Comment: Perhaps it was $\{1,2,3\}^\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: no, unfortunately it was as I wrote it.

Comment: The $\times$ means the Cartesian product, so it's the set of ordered pairs with first component in $\{1,2,3\}$ and second component in $\mathbb{Z}$. That set is countable.

Comment: The "x" probably stands for Cartesian Product.  This is not the same as intersection.  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$, for instance.

A set is countable if it is denumerable.  The original definition due to Cantor comes from a technique of putting the natural numbers into a complete one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers.  This is accomplished by specifying a rule that can be followed as far as one would care to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That set is not uncountable. In fact $(a, b) \mapsto 3b+a-1$ is a bijection from your set to $\mathbb{Z}$!

Explanation: Two sets $A, B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection between them. That is, if there is a function $f: A \to B$ so that each $b \in B$ corresponds with exactly one $a \in A$. Now, the function I have given maps from $\{1, 2, 3\} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. It takes some element of the first set like $(2,7)$ and maps it to $3 \cdot 7+2-1=22$. You can check that each integer corresponds with exactly one ordered pair in $\{1, 2, 3\} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Thus this is a bijection! Thus, your set has the same cardinality as the integers. But the integers are in bijection with the naturals (see if you can find such a function) thus, all these sets have the same cardinality as the natural numbers. We refer to such sets as "countable".

Comment: I'm really new to Discrete Mathematics (first week) so I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean by (a, b) -> 3b + a - 1, could you possibly give me a brief explanation?

Comment: Does that make more sense? Let me know if I can clarify further!

Comment: That was perfect, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: any reason why you subtracted 1? It is a bijection without -1 ;)

Comment: Yeah, that does look pretty strange in hindsight. In my mind I was thinking of $\{1,2,3\} \times \mathbb{Z}$ as encoding "division by 3 with remainder" so that we can write $x=3b+(a-1)$ where the remainder of $x$ divided by $3$ is $a-1$ and $ 0 \leq a-1<3$.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\times$ is not an intersection. Intersection is almost always represented by $\cap$. The $\times$ is a Cartesian product, so the set 
$$A\times B = \{(a,b) ~~| ~~a\in A, b\in B\}$$

Which means that $\{1,2,3\}\times\Bbb{Z}$ is basically $3$ "copies" of $\Bbb{Z}$, or equivalently a countably infinite number of copies of $\{1,2,3\}$. This can be put into bijection with the integers explicitly, as Alexander pointed out, or simply by thinking of a picture similar to the diagonalization argument proving that $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable, but going horizontally and in both directions. Therefore it is countable.